# Set Table character-set/collation using Hibernate Dialect?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I use Hibernate MySQLInnoDB Dialect to generate DDL's.

hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
```

How can I configure the character-set/Collation to 'utf8_general_ci' for the generated table?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same requirement before and used [this](http://blog.tremend.ro/2007/08/14/how-to-set-the-default-charset-to-utf-8-for-create-table-when-using-hibernate-with-java-persistence-annotations/) article which provides the solutions in great detail. You need to subclass **[MySQLInnoDBDialect](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLInnoDBDialect.html)** and override the **[getTableTypeString](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLInnoDBDialect.html#getTableTypeString())** method. More in the article.