# How to set collation for table attribute as utf8_bin in either annotation or application.properties file using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

How do I set the collation for table attribute as utf8_bin in either annotation or the application.properties file using Spring Boot?

I have tried many ways but they did not work. Can you help?

I have tried the following ways.

First: Using @Column annotation like this:

```
@Column(name = "user_id",columnDefinition="VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_bin")
```

Second:

```
 @Column(columnDefinition="VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin")
```

Third: Using application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.collationConnection=utf8_bin
```

Fourth:

```
spring.datasource.url =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iot_schema?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_bin&characterSetResults=utf8
```

Comment: Have any one come out solution for this issue, as I am facing this issue. Please post your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution inspired by answer to similar question: [Set Table character-set/collation using Hibernate Dialect?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1906303/7598851)

Extend the preferred MySQL dialect and override its **getTableTypeString()** method like this:

```java
public class MySQLCustomDialect extends MySQL8Dialect {
    @Override
    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin";
    }
}
```

Set that class to be used in **application.properties**:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=my.package.MySQLCustomDialect
```

Here's the generated SQL query:

```sql
    create table test_table (
      ...
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

**EDIT 3/2022**

As of Hibernate 6 all version specific MySQL dialect classes are deprecated and MySQLDialect should be used instead. By default it sets dialect version to 5.0. That can be fixed by specifying the required version explicitly, for example:

```java
public class MySQL8UnicodeDialect extends MySQLDialect {

    private static final int MY_SQL_DIALECT_VERSION_MAJOR = 8;

    public MySQL8UnicodeDialect() {
        super(DatabaseVersion.make(MY_SQL_DIALECT_VERSION_MAJOR));
    }

    @Override
    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci";
    }
}
```

Comment: It was my problem, too. Your solution helped a lot, thanks!