# Spring JPA MYSQL Character Encoding Case Sensitivity

Tags: spring, jpa, utf-8, character-encoding, case-sensitive

I am using a JPA repository and specified the `findByEmail(email)` method within. When I call this method it works fine, only problem is I want case sensitivity on it. So, "noemail@noemail" would not match "nOeMaIl@NoEmAiL.cOm". This is not happening as the `findByEmail(email)' method is returning this as true.

When I look at the MYSQL database table, I see the character set as "utf8md4" for each of the fields listed as a string in my entity class. through some reading it looks like case sensitivity works with UTF-8 variations such as "utf8md4_0900_as_cs", not sure how to change this if that is the case.

How can I change things to make sure the findByEmail(email) method returns false when case does not match?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="username"})})
@Data
public class user{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Can't be blank")
    @Size(max = 250, message = "Can't exceed 60 characters")
    @Email
    private String email;

    public user() {}

    public user(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<user, Long> {
    List<user> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

```
@PostMapping("/v1/endpoint")
public ResponseEntity<?> forgotusername(@RequestBody String email){
    List<user> users = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:AWS?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need case sensitive collation for utf8 fields, you should use `utf8_bin`. You can extend the MySQL dialect to achieve this. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430786/how-to-set-collation-for-table-attribute-as-utf8-bin-in-either-annotation-or-app).

Comment: I tried this, still doesn't change the "utf8md4" character set in the table. I also cleared the database to start fresh with this config, it boots up, but still doesn't catch the case sensitivity.